# Angular directive *ngIf not working as intended

Tags: html, angular

I have this block of html in my template to show or hide the div.

```
<div *ngIf="csvVisible">
  <p>Paragraph works</p>
</div>
```

This is my component.

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  csvVisible: boolean = false;

  private dataSource: string[];

  @ViewChild(MatTable, { static: true }) table: MatTable<any>;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private templateParserService: TemplateParserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.templateParserService.subscribe({
      next(result: string[]) {
        if (result !== null) {
          this.dataSource = result;

          if (this.dataSource && this.dataSource.length) {
            this.csvVisible = true;
          } else {
            this.csvVisible = false;
          }
        }
      },
      error(error: Error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

Eventhough the DIV is hidden at start, it doesnt automatically show / hide on the `csvVisible` value change. Value of `csvVisible` is properly set when the observer emits data. `[hidden]="csvVisible"` isn't working either.

**Edit :**

Subscriber registration on the service is done by the following code.

```
  private subject = new Subject<string[]>();

  public subscribe(observer: any): Subscription {
    return this.subject.subscribe(observer);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Object inside subscribe, **this** points to current subscribe object, Instead of using subscribe({next:()}) try using this way

**component.ts**

```
 this.templateParserService.subscribe((result: string[])=>{
            if (result !== null) {
                 this.dataSource = result;
               if (this.dataSource && this.dataSource.length) {
                 this.csvVisible = true;
              } else {
                 this.csvVisible = false;
              }
            }
    },(error: Error)=>{
            console.log(error.message);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This did work without the error function as subscrribe only takes one argument.

Comment: I am using a custom subscriber for my service. Its not a HttpClient response but a cusom emitter. I have updated the code including the subscribe method.

Comment: try this public subscribe(...observer: any) {
    return this.subject.subscribe(...observer);
  }